# Is it possible to use one player id with different EXTERNAL USER IDs in OneSignal

Tags: xamarin.forms, onesignal

I have a xamarin.forms application with OneSignal push notification.

It works good, but what I want now is:

In my app it is possible, that you can add different users.
For each user (PLAYER ID) a new EXTERNAL USER ID should be created or a new {user_type} tag.

For now I have the problem, that only one Player ID in OneSignal for one device exists and the EXTERNAL USER ID or {user_type} tag will be always changed.

I need one PLAYER ID (which is unique for one device) with several EXTERNAL USER IDs or several {user_type} tags.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on the page of OneSignal.

You can work with `RemoveExternalUserId` and `SetExternalUserId`.

Everytime a user logs in `SetExternalUserId` and if he logs out use `RemoveExternalUserId`.

To understand how it is working check out [this link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/users).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it does not work at the moment

Completed setting external user id: gh6GSRZinSXus6eduQSxFryniWo1with results: {"push":{"success":true}}

Completed removing external user id with results: {"push":{"success":true}}

Completed setting external user id: jWOKdLfnNrfgwHkbq0d3XrwNGIi2with results: {"push":{"success":false}}